# User role based access control in Kusto Azure Data Explorer Dashboards

Tags: access-control, azure-data-explorer, kql

is it possible by e.g. a mapping table for users and their roles to enable users to only read specific values in database tables (filtered rows)?
Kind regards,

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/rowlevelsecuritypolicy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Row Level Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/rowlevelsecuritypolicy)

Here is a quick demo

```
.set-or-replace MyEventsTable <|
range EventID from 1 to 10 step 1
| extend EventTimestamp = ago(365d*rand())
| extend UserEmail = tostring(pack_array("tic@microsoft.com", "tac@microsoft.com", current_principal_details().UserPrincipalName)[toint(rand(3))])
```

---

```
 MyEventsTable
```

| EventID | EventTimestamp | UserEmail |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 2021-07-31T04:22:12.2312141Z | {redacted manually}@microsoft.com |
| 4 | 2021-07-31T22:24:13.1675234Z | {redacted manually}@microsoft.com |
| 1 | 2021-08-11T06:30:55.6696579Z | {redacted manually}@microsoft.com |
| 6 | 2021-09-08T16:43:24.3680381Z | tic@microsoft.com |
| 3 | 2021-09-18T23:16:14.4731615Z | {redacted manually}@microsoft.com |
| 5 | 2021-09-26T04:46:08.4652178Z | tac@microsoft.com |
| 2 | 2022-01-08T13:21:33.908322Z | tac@microsoft.com |
| 10 | 2022-01-12T00:53:07.087596Z | {redacted manually}@microsoft.com |
| 7 | 2022-03-23T18:55:29.1402369Z | tac@microsoft.com |
| 8 | 2022-04-25T20:23:31.7764039Z | tic@microsoft.com |

```
.create-or-alter function MyEventsTable_RLS(){
    MyEventsTable
    | where UserEmail == current_principal_details().UserPrincipalName
    | extend UserEmail = strcat("*****", extract("(@.*)", 1, UserEmail))
}
```

---

```
.alter table MyEventsTable policy row_level_security enable "MyEventsTable_RLS"
```

---

```
MyEventsTable
```

| EventID | EventTimestamp | UserEmail |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 2021-07-31T04:22:12.2312141Z | *****@microsoft.com |
| 4 | 2021-07-31T22:24:13.1675234Z | *****@microsoft.com |
| 1 | 2021-08-11T06:30:55.6696579Z | *****@microsoft.com |
| 3 | 2021-09-18T23:16:14.4731615Z | *****@microsoft.com |
| 10 | 2022-01-12T00:53:07.087596Z | *****@microsoft.com |